# How to empty name cache on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, cache, vfs

The name cache on FreeBSD is responsible for caching file names and their vnodes. It also provides a special database for hashing the contents of large directories.

I would like to know how to empty the name cache but I cannot find any tool or sysctl that would allow me to do that.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The NetBSD's manual page for [namecache(9)](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=namecache&sektion=9&manpath=NetBSD%209.0) suggests that `cache_purgevfs()` is called when a file system is unmounted. A quick grep around the FreeBSD kernel sources confirm that this is the case on FreeBSD as well.

Unmounting a file system and then mounting it back again is certainly a way to purge cache, but it would be cool to know if there is a less drastic way to do that (e.g., one a per-file basis).